# Debugging outofmemoryexception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, debugging

In the bug fixing of a small ASP.NET/C# web app I have made, I have encountered an OutOfMemoryException.

There is no tips as to where to look as this is a compile time error. How can I diagnose this exception? I am assuming this is exactly where memory profiling comes into play? Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean, it's a compile time error? Is the compiler throwing an OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: A compile time out of memory would indicate that you've got some REALLY weird source code. The only way that I can think of in C++ to do that would be recursive include files (i.e. a.h includes b.h while b.h includes a.h) - does C# have some similar concept? You've basically got to be doing something that's causing the parse tree to blow up.

Comment: Yes, the compiler itself is throwing the error. There is no ysod, but an error in the output window when attempting to debug.

I  think the culprit is I have a 3mb xml file which I parse (it has rss feeds) and then display in a custom rss feed reader. I closed the dev web server and got it sorted.

Comment: In my case, it was a crystal report ( RPT file) who was causing all the trouble, i exclude the file and the proyect started to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a memory dump of your program at the point in time OutOfMemoryException occurs and analyze what's taking up so much memory.

Tess Ferrandez has an [excellent How-To series](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/15/net-debugging-demos-lab-3-memory.aspx) on her blog.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things I can suggest here:

1) Maybe your machine is running out of memory. Check out some ideas on http://digioz.blogspot.com/2008/11/visual-studio-systemoutofmemory.html

2) Try compiling the project outside of visual studio using the VS Command line utility and run msbuild "SolutionfileName.sln". Does your it still crash then?

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you mean runtime error, and not compile-time error.

Typically this would happen if you have a list growing, which is saved in a static field or a system-wide ASP.NET container.

You can run the application in a profiler, like:

[Red gate ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry above, but to me it has happened more than 3 times - Redgate broke either VS or the whole Windows ... 
Try this [approach](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355). 
I quess the root cause for your problem is weak debugging , check [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html). 
Also simple 
if ( DebuggingFlag == true ) 
Response.Write ( "DebugMsg" )

might be useful as simple and absurd it sounds ...